# Всем привет! Прошу помощи с запросом в SQlite3 из Python!

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3, datetime, агрегация

Есть БД всего с четырьмя полями:

(d_t timestamp PRYMARY KEY,  h_p INT, l_p INT,  p_u INT)

В БД записываются результаты измерений - минимум одно в сутки, максимум - 10; далее выводятся на график. Все это я сделал, работает нормально.
Теперь возникла задача строить ещё один график со средними значениями трёх полей измерений за день. Сейчас я смог это сделать очень "кривым" способом - выборкой всех дат и сравнением даты и времени во вложенных циклах, определением количества измерений в сутки и далее выборкой измерений и их усреднением.
Думаю, что должен быть способ просто через запрос, но с datetime никак не могу справится.
Как можно выбрать данные за первый день, усреднить их, потом за следующий и тд.
В результате хочется получить четыре списка - дату (без часов и минут) и средние результаты за день.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Группируете по дате, конвертируя поле d_t при помощи функции `DATE` и используете агрегирующие функции `AVG` для полей для получения средних значений и `COUNT` для получения количества измерений на протяжении дня:

```sql
select date(d_t) d, count(*) cc, avg(h_p), avg(l_p), avg(p_u)
from tbl
group by date(d_t)
order by d
```

[Онлайн демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8363f/1)

Comment: Волшебство! Все работает! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

> Как можно выбрать данные за первый день

```
select * from <Имя Вашей таблицы> where d_t > <Начало суток> and d_t < <Конец суток>
```

Comment: Это подходит для получения всех данных за один конкретный день, а не для агрегации, о чём указано в вопросе: _Как можно выбрать данные за первый день, усреднить их, потом за следующий и тд_